# cocos2d wait for action to finish in Python

Tags: python, cocos2d-x, pyglet

Here is my code.

```
self.wolf.do(MoveTo((x, y + 10)))

sprites = (self.farmer, self.boat,self.wolf)
for n in sprites:
    n.do(MoveBy((-350, 0), 1))
```

I want to wait to finish wolf's action, before run on for loop.What can I do?

Comment: If you know how long the wolf's action is, you can temporary suspend further script execution using [sleep](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep)

Comment: you can also use CallFunc to activate action at the proper time or use sth like that
n.do(Sequence(DelayTime(yourTime), MoveBy((-350, 0), 1))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call some function after the "MoveTo" action is finished you can use the Sequence "+" operator with the CallFunc :

```
self.wolf.do(MoveTo((x, y + 10)) + CallFunc(self.on_move_completed))
```